# Why is sometimes the exe-files locked by windows?

Tags: files, executable

We have an inhouse application Fattracs that is used by 10-30 users over Citrix. All users have starts an own instans. The exe-file resides on several servers with Windows 2003 R2 that is loadbalanced by Citrix. When a new version arrives the exe-files must be changed. If there is only a few users it used to work to change the exe-file on the fly. New users then got the new versions and existing users have to restart to get it. But with many users Windows may somehow lock the exe-file. Then we have to kick out all users before the change.

Someone who knows the reason and even better how to solve it ? We have some fileshares to the directory for exes as we don't want to use Remote desktop all the time for access it. Does it mean anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command "net file" on the server hosting the shared file to see what users have the file open.

Use the command "net file /close" on the same box to force any session returned by the first command to be closed.

Then you will be able to update the file.

```
C:\Users\tf>net file /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET FILE
[id [/CLOSE]]
```

Alternatively use the Shares section in Computer Management to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to find who is locking the files. And even to remove the lock. Alas, its not a safe operation. Maybe the user who is running the application will dynamically load a dll that you have just replaced with an incompatible version. I don't thing that it is related to the share ( the handle utility will tell you about it ) and I don't know of a solution to this:-(.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what [GNU Emacs](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/emacs/emacs/nt/runemacs.c?revision=1.20&view=markup) does.

When it starts up, it looks for a newer version; a `emacs-`*version*`.exe` where *version* is newer than the current version. Then they install `emacs.exe` and `emacs-`*version*`.exe` and only complain if the latter can't be installed.

For in-house stuff, if you don't have versions, simply consider looking for `main-1.exe`, and failing that `main-2.exe` and so on, and simply create a new file whenever it's installed. The make `main.exe` search for the highest-numbered version.

Your installer could also remove older `main-`*N*`.exe` files, if you like.